# Variable value not remaining on set variable

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the health of a monster at the start, and it works absolutely fine, but when I see in the inspector I see "0" health.

In the start it works fine, it shows the right health "200", but a second later it shows in the inspector of the monster + in the console that the health is "0". So at the start, the monster script should get the health (int) from another script.

I hope you can find out what's wrong because trust me I am good at coding but I'm trying to figure out over 2 days what's wrong.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MonsterData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int MonHealth;
    public string[] items;
    private string MonsterDataLink ="https://000webhostapp.com/SetMonster.php";
    private string MonsterGetDataLink = "https://000webhostapp.com/GetMonsterData.php";
    [SerializeField] private string MonsterName;
    [SerializeField] private int Health,Exp, RunesMin, RunesMax, Item,Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4,Item5,Item6,Item7,Level,DEF,Attack;
    [SerializeField] private int MonsterID;

    private void Start()
    {
        //StartCoroutine(GetMonsterData(MonsterID));
        //StartCoroutine(CreateMonster(MonsterName,Health, Exp, RunesMin,RunesMax, Item, Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6, Item7,Level,DEF,Attack));
    }

    IEnumerator CreateMonster(string MonsterName,int Health,int Exp,int RunesMin,int RunesMax,int Item,int Item1,int Item2,int Item3,int Item4,int Item5,int Item6,int Item7,int Level,int DEF, int Attack)
    {
        WWWForm MonsterRegister = new WWWForm();
        MonsterRegister.AddField("NamePost", MonsterName);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("HealthPost", Health);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("ExpPost", Exp);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("RunesMinPost", RunesMin);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("RunesMaxPost", RunesMax);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("ItemPost", Item);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("Item1Post", Item1);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("Item2Post", Item2);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("Item3Post", Item3);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("Item4Post", Item4);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("Item5Post", Item5);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("Item6Post", Item6);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("Item7Post", Item7);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("LevelPost", Level);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("DEFPost", DEF);
        MonsterRegister.AddField("AttackPost", Attack);
        WWW wwwRegister = new WWW(MonsterDataLink, MonsterRegister);
        yield return wwwRegister;
        Debug.Log(wwwRegister.text);
    }
    public IEnumerator GetMonsterData(int MonsterID)
    {
        WWWForm MonsterGetData = new WWWForm();
        MonsterGetData.AddField("MonsterIDPost", MonsterID);
        WWW wwwMonsterData = new WWW(MonsterGetDataLink, MonsterGetData);
        yield return wwwMonsterData;
        string MonsterDataString = wwwMonsterData.text;
        items = MonsterDataString.Split(';');
        string Data = (GetDataValue(items[MonsterID - 1], "Health:"));
        yield return Data;
        Debug.Log(Data);
        GetInfo(Data);
    }
    public string GetDataValue(string data, string index)
    {
        string value = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(index) + 
                index.Length);
        value = value.Remove(value.IndexOf("|"));
        return value;
    }
    private void GetInfo(string health)
    {
        int sethealth = int.Parse(health);
        MonsterMove mons = new MonsterMove();
        Debug.Log(sethealth);
        mons.SetHealth(sethealth);
    }
}
```

The monster code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MonsterMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region //start
    public int StartingHealth;
    private int starts;
    [SerializeField] private int MonsterID=1;
    public Animator anim;
    public bool IdleAnimBool = false;
    public bool PatrolAnimBool = true;
    [SerializeField]
    private float TimeCounterStartPatrol,FixedPatrolTime;
    private float RandomTimePatrol, TimeCounterBasePatrol;
    [SerializeField]
    private float TimeCounterStartIdle,FixedIdleTime;
    private float RandomIdleTime, TimeCounterBaseIdle;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool ShouldBeIdle=false;
    public float MonsterMoveSpeed;
    public float Distance=2f;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool ShouldBePatroling = true;
    private bool MovingRight = true;
    public Transform groundDetection;
    #endregion 
    private void Start()
    {
        MonsterData mons = new MonsterData();
        StartCoroutine(mons.GetMonsterData(MonsterID));
        MonsterMoveSpeed = Random.Range(1, 1.3f);
        TimeCounterBasePatrol = TimeCounterStartPatrol;
        TimeCounterBaseIdle = TimeCounterStartIdle;
        RandomTimePatrol = Random.Range(0f, TimeCounterStartPatrol-FixedPatrolTime);
        RandomIdleTime = Random.Range(0f, TimeCounterStartIdle-FixedIdleTime);
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(StartingHealth);
        if (ShouldBePatroling&&!ShouldBeIdle)
        {
            Move();
            PatrolTime();
            PatrolAnim();
            anim.SetBool("run", true);
            anim.SetBool("idle", false);
        }
        if (ShouldBeIdle==true&&!ShouldBePatroling) {
            IdleAnim();
            IdleTime();
            anim.SetBool("run", false);
            anim.SetBool("idle", true);
        }
    }
    void Move()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.right * MonsterMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        int layer_mask1 = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
        RaycastHit2D groundInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(groundDetection.position, Vector2.down, Distance, layer_mask1);
        if (groundInfo.collider == false)
        {
            if (MovingRight == true)
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 
                                               -180, 0);
                MovingRight = false;
            }
            else
            {
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 
                                  0, 0);
                MovingRight = true;
            }
        }
    }
    private void PatrolTime()
    {
        TimeCounterStartPatrol -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        if (TimeCounterStartPatrol <= RandomTimePatrol)
        {
            ShouldBePatroling = !ShouldBePatroling;
            ShouldBeIdle = !ShouldBeIdle;
            TimeCounterStartPatrol = 
           TimeCounterBasePatrol;
        }
    }
    private void IdleTime()
    {
        TimeCounterStartIdle -= Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        if (TimeCounterStartIdle <= RandomIdleTime)
        {
            ShouldBePatroling = !ShouldBePatroling;
            ShouldBeIdle = !ShouldBeIdle;
            TimeCounterStartIdle = TimeCounterBaseIdle;
        }
    }
    private void IdleAnim()
    {
        if (IdleAnimBool == true && PatrolAnimBool == false)
        {
            IdleAnimBool = false;
            PatrolAnimBool = true;
        }
    }
    private void PatrolAnim()
    {
        if (PatrolAnimBool == true && IdleAnimBool == false)
        {
            PatrolAnimBool = false;
            IdleAnimBool = true;
        }
    }
    private void ChangeAnim()
    {

    }
    public void SetHealth(int health)
    {
        StartingHealth = health;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably should first use the same naming convention everwhere, this is pretty hard to read... And so much bool / code that does "nothing". Please try to refractor a bit

Comment: This line: *`MonsterMove mons = new MonsterMove();`* is either a simplification that you gave us, or code that won't work because you can't call `new` on MonoBehaviour objects, Unity will throw an error. But even if it didn't, you don't save that object anywhere and it gets garbage collected two lines later.